How to transform structured data between JATS and MODS format?
How can structured data in a file jats.xml (e.g. publication metadata, such as authors and title) in FilesAndJATS packaging format https://datahub.deepgreen.org/FilesAndJATS (does not open in browser) be transformed to mods.xml in METSMODS packaging format http://purl.org/net/sword/package/METSMODS (does not open in browser)?
Presumably, it can be done by an XSL transformation, but how would it work in detail, particularly the corresponding xls-file? This task seems too common (two popular formats) for me, to start from scratch.
In the following, I give an example of two xml-files, one in each format, note that the data behind are different, since I do not know yet, how to transform from one to the other:
mods.xml
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<mets:mets xmlns:mets="http://www.loc.gov/METS/" xmlns:mods="http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.loc.gov/METS/ http://www.loc.gov/mets/mets.xsd http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3 https://www.loc.gov/standards/mods/v3/mods.xsd" ID="sword-mets_mets" OBJID="sword-mets" LABEL="METS/MODS SWORD Item" PROFILE="METS/MODS SIP Profile 1.0">
  <mets:metsHdr CREATEDATE="2024-04-25T18:05:40.685198">
    <mets:agent ROLE="CUSTODIAN" TYPE="ORGANIZATION">
      <mets:name>DeepGreen</mets:name>
    </mets:agent>
  </mets:metsHdr>
  <mets:dmdSec ID="sword-mets-dmd-1" GROUPID="sword-mets-dmd-1_group-1">
    <mets:mdWrap LABEL="SWAP Metadata" MDTYPE="MODS" MIMETYPE="text/xml">
      <mets:xmlData>
        <mods:mods xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3 https://www.loc.gov/standards/mods/v3/mods-3-6.xsd">
          <mods:typeOfResource>text</mods:typeOfResource>
          <mods:genre>journal article</mods:genre>
          <mods:language>
            <mods:languageTerm type="code" authority="rfc3066">en</mods:languageTerm>
          </mods:language>
          <mods:titleInfo>
            <mods:title>fancy title</mods:title>
          </mods:titleInfo>
          <mods:relatedItem type="host">
            <mods:titleInfo>
              <mods:title>Journal of Coolness</mods:title>
            </mods:titleInfo>
            <mods:titleInfo type="abbreviated">
              <mods:title>J. Mater. Cool. A</mods:title>
            </mods:titleInfo>
            <mods:identifier type="issn">1111-1111</mods:identifier>
            <mods:identifier type="eIssn">2222-1111</mods:identifier>
            <mods:identifier type="publisher-id">TA</mods:identifier>
            <mods:identifier type="coden">JMCAET</mods:identifier>
            <mods:part>
              <mods:detail type="volume">
                <mods:number>12</mods:number>
              </mods:detail>
              <mods:detail type="issue">
                <mods:number>13</mods:number>
              </mods:detail>
              <mods:extent unit="pages">
                <mods:start>7742</mods:start>
                <mods:end>7753</mods:end>
                <mods:total>12</mods:total>
              </mods:extent>
            </mods:part>
          </mods:relatedItem>
          <mods:name type="personal">
            <mods:namePart type="family">Famnam</mods:namePart>
            <mods:namePart type="given">M.</mods:namePart>
            <mods:role>
              <mods:roleTerm type="text">author</mods:roleTerm>
            </mods:role>
            <mods:nameIdentifier type="orcid">https://orcid.org/0000-0000-0000-0000</mods:nameIdentifier>
            <mods:affiliation>              
        </mods:affiliation>
            <mods:affiliation>
        </mods:affiliation>
          </mods:name>
          <mods:name type="personal">
            <mods:namePart type="family">Name1</mods:namePart>
            <mods:namePart type="given">J.</mods:namePart>
            <mods:role>
              <mods:roleTerm type="text">author</mods:roleTerm>
            </mods:role>
            <mods:affiliation>
        </mods:affiliation>
          </mods:name>
          <mods:name type="personal">
            <mods:namePart type="family">Name2</mods:namePart>
            <mods:namePart type="given">M.</mods:namePart>
            <mods:role>
              <mods:roleTerm type="text">author</mods:roleTerm>
            </mods:role>
            <mods:affiliation>
        </mods:affiliation>
          </mods:name>
          <mods:name type="personal">
            <mods:namePart type="family">Name3</mods:namePart>
            <mods:namePart type="given">D.</mods:namePart>
            <mods:role>
              <mods:roleTerm type="text">author</mods:roleTerm>
            </mods:role>
            <mods:nameIdentifier type="orcid">https://orcid.org/0000-0000-0000-0000</mods:nameIdentifier>
            <mods:affiliation>
        </mods:affiliation>
          </mods:name>
          <mods:name type="personal">
            <mods:namePart type="family">Name4</mods:namePart>
            <mods:namePart type="given">M.</mods:namePart>
            <mods:role>
              <mods:roleTerm type="text">author</mods:roleTerm>
            </mods:role>
            <mods:affiliation>
        </mods:affiliation>
            <mods:affiliation>   
        </mods:affiliation>
          </mods:name>
          <mods:abstract><![CDATA[<p xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">too abstract</p>]]></mods:abstract>
          <mods:abstract><![CDATA[<p xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">abstract</p>]]></mods:abstract>
          <mods:originInfo>
            <mods:publisher>The Royal Society of Coolness</mods:publisher>
            <mods:place>
              <mods:placeTerm type="text"/>
            </mods:place>
            <mods:dateIssued encoding="iso8601">2024-02-16</mods:dateIssued>
            <mods:dateOther encoding="iso8601" type="received">2023-11-23</mods:dateOther>
            <mods:dateOther encoding="iso8601" type="accepted">2024-02-13</mods:dateOther>
          </mods:originInfo>
          <mods:identifier type="publisher-id">22222222222</mods:identifier>
          <mods:identifier type="doi">11.1111/11111111111</mods:identifier>
          <mods:accessCondition type="use and reproduction"/>
          <mods:note type="funding">
            Funding
          </mods:note>
        </mods:mods>
      </mets:xmlData>
    </mets:mdWrap>
  </mets:dmdSec>
  <mets:fileSec xmlns="http://www.loc.gov/METS/">
    <mets:fileGrp ID="sword-mets-fgrp-1" USE="CONTENT">
      <mets:file GROUPID="sword-mets-fgid-1" ID="sword-mets-file-001" CHECKSUM="ae7958a6cd81c81f74f04b80345f7cdc" CHECKSUMTYPE="MD5" MIMETYPE="application/pdf">
        <mets:FLocat LOCTYPE="URL" xlink:href="D3TA07243F.pdf"/>
      </mets:file>
      <mets:file GROUPID="sword-mets-fgid-2" ID="sword-mets-file-002" CHECKSUM="64b5eac528e95a16f002560d2b3b4353" CHECKSUMTYPE="MD5" MIMETYPE="image/tiff">
        <mets:FLocat LOCTYPE="URL" xlink:href="d3ta07243f-f1.tif"/>
      </mets:file>
      <mets:file GROUPID="sword-mets-fgid-3" ID="sword-mets-file-003" CHECKSUM="3d1c01013c8dead37a9d5ce9fb6865f8" CHECKSUMTYPE="MD5" MIMETYPE="image/tiff">
        <mets:FLocat LOCTYPE="URL" xlink:href="d3ta07243f-f2.tif"/>
      </mets:file>
      <mets:file GROUPID="sword-mets-fgid-4" ID="sword-mets-file-004" CHECKSUM="3e9ecbd5d24fae851898e4c041eb65c8" CHECKSUMTYPE="MD5" MIMETYPE="image/tiff">
        <mets:FLocat LOCTYPE="URL" xlink:href="d3ta07243f-f3.tif"/>
      </mets:file>
      <mets:file GROUPID="sword-mets-fgid-5" ID="sword-mets-file-005" CHECKSUM="abaca78a82e6d7c9e17ae8f387d5cdc0" CHECKSUMTYPE="MD5" MIMETYPE="image/tiff">
        <mets:FLocat LOCTYPE="URL" xlink:href="d3ta07243f-f4.tif"/>
      </mets:file>
      <mets:file GROUPID="sword-mets-fgid-6" ID="sword-mets-file-006" CHECKSUM="f5ccfc4452f86c06046c08a5053cb168" CHECKSUMTYPE="MD5" MIMETYPE="image/tiff">
        <mets:FLocat LOCTYPE="URL" xlink:href="d3ta07243f-f5.tif"/>
      </mets:file>
      <mets:file GROUPID="sword-mets-fgid-7" ID="sword-mets-file-007" CHECKSUM="e2994ffc3808725b85c75f9625c9788f" CHECKSUMTYPE="MD5" MIMETYPE="image/tiff">
        <mets:FLocat LOCTYPE="URL" xlink:href="d3ta07243f-f6.tif"/>
      </mets:file>
      <mets:file GROUPID="sword-mets-fgid-8" ID="sword-mets-file-008" CHECKSUM="163c3ba161730dda1b3d9c94b1092598" CHECKSUMTYPE="MD5" MIMETYPE="image/tiff">
        <mets:FLocat LOCTYPE="URL" xlink:href="d3ta07243f-ga.tif"/>
      </mets:file>
      <mets:file GROUPID="sword-mets-fgid-9" ID="sword-mets-file-009" CHECKSUM="1c5d6c3b74d3eeb7da0e9cf10d71b01f" CHECKSUMTYPE="MD5" MIMETYPE="image/tiff">
        <mets:FLocat LOCTYPE="URL" xlink:href="d3ta07243f-t1.tif"/>
      </mets:file>
      <mets:file GROUPID="sword-mets-fgid-10" ID="sword-mets-file-010" CHECKSUM="0c779a34bdf9c156ef5e0d1e07c83052" CHECKSUMTYPE="MD5" MIMETYPE="image/tiff">
        <mets:FLocat LOCTYPE="URL" xlink:href="d3ta07243f-t2.tif"/>
      </mets:file>
      <mets:file GROUPID="sword-mets-fgid-11" ID="sword-mets-file-011" CHECKSUM="17e3dc2a30e233323f90125809e48e7c" CHECKSUMTYPE="MD5" MIMETYPE="image/tiff">
        <mets:FLocat LOCTYPE="URL" xlink:href="d3ta07243f-t3.tif"/>
      </mets:file>
      <mets:file GROUPID="sword-mets-fgid-12" ID="sword-mets-file-012" CHECKSUM="2443969ad74b130108420c7bb6b61d8f" CHECKSUMTYPE="MD5" MIMETYPE="image/tiff">
        <mets:FLocat LOCTYPE="URL" xlink:href="d3ta07243f-t4.tif"/>
      </mets:file>
      <mets:file GROUPID="sword-mets-fgid-13" ID="sword-mets-file-013" CHECKSUM="aecdc150e74d7f9d27b8d9ea2927e620" CHECKSUMTYPE="MD5" MIMETYPE="image/tiff">
        <mets:FLocat LOCTYPE="URL" xlink:href="d3ta07243f-t5.tif"/>
      </mets:file>
      <mets:file GROUPID="sword-mets-fgid-14" ID="sword-mets-file-014" CHECKSUM="1496c76609f721171d80598ad3fa3607" CHECKSUMTYPE="MD5" MIMETYPE="image/tiff">
        <mets:FLocat LOCTYPE="URL" xlink:href="d3ta07243f-t6.tif"/>
      </mets:file>
      <mets:file GROUPID="sword-mets-fgid-15" ID="sword-mets-file-015" CHECKSUM="1ab0295a1821dfd841f88f2a9b4df5ac" CHECKSUMTYPE="MD5" MIMETYPE="image/tiff">
        <mets:FLocat LOCTYPE="URL" xlink:href="d3ta07243f-t7.tif"/>
      </mets:file>
    </mets:fileGrp>
  </mets:fileSec>
  <mets:structMap xmlns="http://www.loc.gov/METS/" ID="sword-mets-struct-1" LABEL="structure" TYPE="LOGICAL">
    <div ID="sword-mets-div-0" DMDID="sword-mets-dmd-1" TYPE="SWORD Object">
      <div ID="sword-mets-div-1" TYPE="File">
        <fptr FILEID="sword-mets-file-001"/>
      </div>
      <div ID="sword-mets-div-2" TYPE="File">
        <fptr FILEID="sword-mets-file-002"/>
      </div>
      <div ID="sword-mets-div-3" TYPE="File">
        <fptr FILEID="sword-mets-file-003"/>
      </div>
      <div ID="sword-mets-div-4" TYPE="File">
        <fptr FILEID="sword-mets-file-004"/>
      </div>
      <div ID="sword-mets-div-5" TYPE="File">
        <fptr FILEID="sword-mets-file-005"/>
      </div>
      <div ID="sword-mets-div-6" TYPE="File">
        <fptr FILEID="sword-mets-file-006"/>
      </div>
      <div ID="sword-mets-div-7" TYPE="File">
        <fptr FILEID="sword-mets-file-007"/>
      </div>
      <div ID="sword-mets-div-8" TYPE="File">
        <fptr FILEID="sword-mets-file-008"/>
      </div>
      <div ID="sword-mets-div-9" TYPE="File">
        <fptr FILEID="sword-mets-file-009"/>
      </div>
      <div ID="sword-mets-div-10" TYPE="File">
        <fptr FILEID="sword-mets-file-010"/>
      </div>
      <div ID="sword-mets-div-11" TYPE="File">
        <fptr FILEID="sword-mets-file-011"/>
      </div>
      <div ID="sword-mets-div-12" TYPE="File">
        <fptr FILEID="sword-mets-file-012"/>
      </div>
      <div ID="sword-mets-div-13" TYPE="File">
        <fptr FILEID="sword-mets-file-013"/>
      </div>
      <div ID="sword-mets-div-14" TYPE="File">
        <fptr FILEID="sword-mets-file-014"/>
      </div>
      <div ID="sword-mets-div-15" TYPE="File">
        <fptr FILEID="sword-mets-file-015"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </mets:structMap>
</mets:mets>

jats.xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE article PUBLIC "-//NLM//DTD JATS (Z39.96) Journal Archiving and Interchange DTD with MathML3 v1.2 20190208//EN" "JATS-archivearticle1-mathml3.dtd">
<article xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" dtd-version="1.2" xml:lang="en">
  <front>
    <journal-meta>
      <journal-id journal-id-type="publisher-id">123456</journal-id>
      <journal-id journal-id-type="doi">11.11111/00000.0000-0000</journal-id>
      <journal-title-group>
        <journal-title>Mysterious Earth Sciences</journal-title>
      </journal-title-group>
      <issn pub-type="ppub">2222-2222</issn>
      <issn pub-type="epub">1111-2222</issn>
      <publisher>
        <publisher-name>Jumper</publisher-name>
      </publisher>
    </journal-meta>
    <article-meta>
      <article-id pub-id-type="doi">11.11111/s11111-11-111111-1</article-id>
      <article-categories>
        <subj-group subj-group-type="heading">
          <subject>Editorial</subject>
        </subj-group>
      </article-categories>
      <title-group>
        <article-title xml:lang="en">Mysterous Earth Sciences Progress Report 2020 and Outlook 2021</article-title>
      </title-group>
      <contrib-group>
        <contrib contrib-type="author" id="Au1">
          <name>
            <surname>Surname1</surname>
            <given-names>name1</given-names>
          </name>
          <address>
            <email>a@b.c</email>
          </address>
          <aff>Center</aff>
        </contrib>
        <contrib contrib-type="author" id="Au2">
          <name>
            <surname>Surname2</surname>
            <given-names>Name2</given-names>
          </name>
          <aff>Jumper, Germany</aff>
        </contrib>
        <contrib contrib-type="author" id="Au3">
          <name>
            <surname>Surname3</surname>
            <given-names>Name3</given-names>
          </name>
          <aff>Office</aff>
        </contrib>
        <contrib contrib-type="author" id="Au4">
          <name>
            <surname>SomeName</surname>
            <given-names>Anyname</given-names>
          </name>
          <aff>OfficeUSA</aff>
        </contrib>
        <contrib contrib-type="author" id="Au5">
          <name>
            <surname>Coolname</surname>
            <given-names>hotname</given-names>
          </name>
          <aff>University</aff>
        </contrib>
        <contrib contrib-type="author" id="Au6">
          <name>
            <surname>Foo</surname>
            <given-names>Bar</given-names>
          </name>
          <aff>University</aff>
        </contrib>
        <contrib contrib-type="author" id="Au7">
          <name>
            <surname>John</surname>
            <given-names>Doe</given-names>
          </name>
          <aff>Office</aff>
        </contrib>
        <contrib contrib-type="author" id="Au8">
          <name>
            <surname>Johny</surname>
            <given-names>Doe</given-names>
          </name>
          <aff>Council</aff>
        </contrib>
        <contrib contrib-type="author" id="Au9">
          <name>
            <surname>Jack</surname>
            <given-names>Doe</given-names>
          </name>
          <aff>Centre</aff>
        </contrib>
        <contrib contrib-type="author" id="Au10">
          <name>
            <surname>Jim</surname>
            <given-names>Nastic</given-names>
          </name>
          <aff>University</aff>
        </contrib>
        <contrib contrib-type="author" id="Au11">
          <name>
            <surnameBig</surname>
            <given-names>Mac</given-names>
          </name>
          <aff>Management</aff>
        </contrib>
        <contrib contrib-type="author" id="Au12">
          <name>
            <surname>Merkel</surname>
            <given-names>Angelo</given-names>
          </name>
          <aff>TU</aff>
        </contrib>
        <contrib contrib-type="author" id="Au13">
          <name>
            <surname>Cake</surname>
            <given-names>Pan</given-names>
          </name>
          <aff>TU</aff>
        </contrib>
        <contrib contrib-type="author" id="Au14">
          <name>
            <surname>S14</surname>
            <given-names>N14</given-names>
          </name>
          <aff>University</aff>
        </contrib>
        <contrib contrib-type="author" id="Au15">
          <name>
            <surname>S15</surname>
            <given-names>N15</given-names>
          </name>
          <address>
            <email>editor@web.com</email>
          </address>
          <aff>Office</aff>
        </contrib>
      </contrib-group>
      <pub-date date-type="pub" publication-format="electronic">
        <day>9</day>
        <month>4</month>
        <year>2021</year>
      </pub-date>
      <pub-date date-type="pub" publication-format="print">
        <month>8</month>
        <year>1021</year>
      </pub-date>
      <volume>80</volume>
      <issue>8</issue>
      <elocation-id>314</elocation-id>
      <uri specific-use="web" content-type="html">http://link.springer.com/openurl/fulltext?id=doi:11.11111/s11111-111-11111-1</uri>
      <uri specific-use="web" content-type="pdf">http://link.springer.com/openurl/pdf?id=doi:11.1111/s11111-111-111111-1</uri>
      <permissions>
        <copyright-statement content-type="compact">© The Author(s) 2021</copyright-statement>
        <license license-type="open-access" xlink:href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/">
          <license-p>This is an open-access article distributed under the terms of the Creative Commons Attribution License, 
which permits unrestricted use, distribution, and reproduction in any medium, provided the original work is properly cited.</license-p>
        </license>
      </permissions>
      <abstract xml:lang="en" id="Abs1">
        <title>Abstract</title>
        <p id="Par1">too abstract</p>
      </abstract>
      <kwd-group xml:lang="en">
        <title>Keywords</title>
        <kwd>Mysterious Earth Sciences</kwd>
        <kwd>Most cited papers</kwd>
        <kwd>Progress report</kwd>
        <kwd>2020</kwd>
      </kwd-group>
      <funding-group>
        <award-group>
          <funding-source>
            <institution-wrap>
              <institution>Center</institution>
            </institution-wrap>
          </funding-source>
        </award-group>
      </funding-group>
      <custom-meta-group>
        <custom-meta>
          <meta-name>issue-print-date-year</meta-name>
          <meta-value>1021</meta-value>
        </custom-meta>
        <custom-meta>
          <meta-name>issue-print-date-month</meta-name>
          <meta-value>8</meta-value>
        </custom-meta>
        <custom-meta>
          <meta-name>issue-print-date-day</meta-name>
          <meta-value>20</meta-value>
        </custom-meta>
        <custom-meta>
          <meta-name>issue-type</meta-name>
          <meta-value>Regular</meta-value>
        </custom-meta>
        <custom-meta>
          <meta-name>article-type</meta-name>
          <meta-value>EditorialNotes</meta-value>
        </custom-meta>
        <custom-meta>
          <meta-name>journal-subject-primary</meta-name>
          <meta-value>Earth Sciences</meta-value>
        </custom-meta>
        <custom-meta>
          <meta-name>journal-subject-secondary</meta-name>
          <meta-value>Geology</meta-value>
        </custom-meta>
        <custom-meta>
          <meta-name>journal-subject-secondary</meta-name>
          <meta-value>Hydrology/Water Resources</meta-value>
        </custom-meta>
        <custom-meta>
          <meta-name>journal-subject-secondary</meta-name>
          <meta-value>Geochemistry</meta-value>
        </custom-meta>
        <custom-meta>
          <meta-name>journal-subject-secondary</meta-name>
          <meta-value>Environmental Science and Engineering</meta-value>
        </custom-meta>
        <custom-meta>
          <meta-name>journal-subject-secondary</meta-name>
          <meta-value>Mystery</meta-value>
        </custom-meta>
        <custom-meta>
          <meta-name>journal-subject-secondary</meta-name>
          <meta-value>Biogeosciences</meta-value>
        </custom-meta>
        <custom-meta>
          <meta-name>open-access</meta-name>
          <meta-value>true</meta-value>
        </custom-meta>
      </custom-meta-group>
    </article-meta>
  </front>
</article>


Both your links fail to open.  To make this a legitimate question, please post an example of the input XML, your attempted XSLT stylesheet and the expected result - all as code within your question.

I don't know in which context you work with those formats but I would rather think you should ask other people you (hopefully) know that work with these formats whether they know of any (XSLT) library doing the job. Or wait whether someone shows up here on Stackoverflow that is familiar with the input and output format and knows about any library that could help you out.

The main job, the transformation of the metadata, is derived from this file (thanks to DeepGreen staff)
https://github.com/OA-DeepGreen/jper/blob/develop/service/models/xslt.py
After this transformation, the attached files need to be described, i.e. to add the elements <fileSec> and <structMap>, for which I wrote the following Python-script
import os
import lxml.etree as ET

class XMLNamespaces:
   mets = 'http://www.loc.gov/METS/'
   xlink = 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'

jatsdir = "multifile_jats/"
mimetype = {'.tif':'image/tiff', '.jpg':'image/jpeg', '.png':'image/png', '.gif':'image/gif', '.csv':'text/csv', '.pdf':'application/pdf'}


"""   read in files (JATS xml-file and attached files)   """
files = os.listdir(jatsdir)
nonxmlfiles = []
suffix = set({})
xmlfilecounter = 0
for filename in files:
   file_suffix = filename[-4:]
   if file_suffix =='.xml':
      xmlfile = filename
      xmlfilecounter += 1
   else:
      nonxmlfiles.append(filename)
      suffix.add(file_suffix)


"""   check files   """
if xmlfilecounter == 0:
   print("Error: no xml-file found in {}".format(jatsdir))
   os._exit(1)
if xmlfilecounter > 1:
   print("Error: more than one xml-file found in {}".format(jatsdir))
   os._exit(1)
if not suffix.issubset(mimetype.keys()):
   print("Error: no mimetyp found for file suffix {} in {}".format(suffix.difference(mimetyp.keys()), jatsdir))
   os._exit(1)

jatsfile = jatsdir + xmlfile   # input
xsl  = "jats2metsmods.xslt"   # https://github.com/OA-DeepGreen/jper/blob/develop/service/models/xslt.py
metsfile = jatsdir + "mets.xml"   # output


"""   transform metadata   """
dom = ET.parse(jatsfile)
xslt = ET.parse(xsl)
transform = ET.XSLT(xslt)
newdom = transform(dom)


"""   generate file information   """
root = newdom.getroot()   

fileids = []
fileSec = ET.SubElement(root,    ET.QName(XMLNamespaces.mets, 'fileSec'), xmlns=XMLNamespaces.mets)   
fileGrp = ET.SubElement(fileSec, ET.QName(XMLNamespaces.mets, 'fileGrp'), ID="sword-mets-fgrp-1", USE="CONTENT")
for n, filename in enumerate(nonxmlfiles):
   #groupid = "sword-mets-fgid-" + str(n+1)
   fileid = "sword-mets-file-" + str(n+1).zfill(3)
   fileids.append(fileid)
   file_suffix = filename[-4:]
   
   if file_suffix in mimetype.keys():
      mime = mimetype[file_suffix]
      file = ET.SubElement(fileGrp, ET.QName(XMLNamespaces.mets, 'file'), ID=fileid, MIMETYPE=mime)   # GROUPID=groupid
   else:
      print("Warning: no mimetyp found for file suffix {}".format(file_suffix))
      file = ET.SubElement(fileGrp, ET.QName(XMLNamespaces.mets, 'file'), ID=fileid)   # GROUPID=groupid

   FLocat =  ET.SubElement(file,    ET.QName(XMLNamespaces.mets, 'FLocat'),  LOCTYPE="URL")
   FLocat.attrib[ET.QName(XMLNamespaces.xlink, 'href')] = filename

structMap = ET.SubElement(root, ET.QName(XMLNamespaces.mets, 'structMap'), xmlns=XMLNamespaces.mets, ID="sword-mets-struct-1", LABEL="structure", TYPE="LOGICAL")
div1 =      ET.SubElement(structMap, "div", ID="sword-mets-div-0", DMDID="sword-mets-dmd-1", TYPE="SWORD Object")
for n, fileid in enumerate(fileids):
   divid = "sword-mets-div-" + str(n+1)
   div2 =      ET.SubElement(div1, "div", ID=divid, TYPE="File")
   fptr =      ET.SubElement(div2, "fptr", FILEID=fileid)

"""   write to file (METS)  """
infile = ET.tostring(newdom, pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True, encoding='utf-8')
outfile = open(metsfile, 'wb')
outfile.write(infile)
os._exit(os.EX_OK)

